# Cannot decode Facebook's Https traffic using Fiddler

Tags: fiddler

But only https traffic from Facebook is concerned...
When I click on decode the console flickrs three times, but nothing gets decoded.

When I access SO via https the console flickers a couple of times but decodes the document!

I installed wact from this [site](https://iisnetblogs.blob.core.windows.net/media/thomad/Media/wcatfiddler.zip) but unistalled it afterwards.
Deinstalled fiddler and the deleted the folder under programs\fiddler.

Something is broken now. Hmmm.

[image]